# How to split columns in rows using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a tablix that has a lot of columns, but just one row. I wanna to split these columns in different rows, just for visualization.

What I have:
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6

What I want:
Column 1 | Column 2 
Column 3 | Column 4 
Column 5 | Column 6

Can I do this just using report builder or I need to do some SQL trick to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Both answers helped in my solution... Thanks! Unfortunately I can mark one as correct  =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to use a SQL trick you could change this:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6
FROM Table
WHERE Stuff = @Stuff
```

to this:

```
SELECT 
CASE ExtraRows.RowNum 
    WHEN 1 THEN COL1
    WHEN 2 THEN COL3
    ELSE COL5
END NewColumn1,
-- I leave the other 2 columns for you if you are interested in this solution
FROM
(
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6
FROM Table
WHERE Stuff = @Stuff 
) SubTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 RowNum UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) ExtraRows
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add more rows to your Detail group. Right-click the Detail group handle (it is the grey box on the left with three horizontal lines when the table is selected), choose `Insert Row ->` then `Inside Group - Below` or just `Below` (depending on whether you are on the top row of the group). Now put the columns where you want them.